# Thinking about the cosets of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces, quotient-set

Let's think about

$$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(x))$$

First of all, `(f(x))` is the ideal generated by $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Let's consider $f(x) = x^d+1$. Then, if we multiply all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ by $x^d+1$, we get all polynomials of degree greater than or equal to $d$, plus the polynomial $0$.

So $(f(x)) = \{\mbox{polynomials with degree $\ge d$, and polynomial  0}\}$.

Now I'm trying to think about the cosets, that is, $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(x)) = \{p(f(x)), p\in \mathbb{Z}[x]\}$

I should think about all possible cosets and then consider which ones are equivalent so thus discover how this ring looks like. However, I see $p(f(x))$ gives me again all polynomials with degree $\ge d$.

I think something is deeply wrong in my understanding of cosets, as this quotient should be isomorphic to the space of all polynomials of degree up to $d-1$.

Comment: You don't get all polynomials.  You only get those whose coefficients of terms $n$ and $n+d$ are the same

Comment: @Alan what about the polynomial $x * (x^d+1)$? $x$ is from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $x^d+1$ from $(f(x))$

Comment: Yes, that one has coefficients of the $d+1$ and $1$ terms the same.,  $n=1$

Comment: It's more beneficial to think about $\Bbb Z[x]/(f(x))$ as *adjoining* an element $x$ to the ring $\Bbb Z$ such that $f(x)=0$ (but $x$ is not the root of any proper divisor of $f$). Just like in $\Bbb C\cong\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @Berci indeed but I noticed that my coset knowledge was flawed so I wanted to understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Alan I don't get. $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ has infinitely many coefficients, so the product would also have infinitely many

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I'm confused about the second part of the question on which there's a bounty : going modulo a polynomial is the same as taking the remainder modulo that polynomial, so it's long division? It's true that there are some tricks like the remainder theorem for linear polynomials and so on, but it doesn't contain any huge revelations.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that $(f(x))$ doesn't contain every polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, as it has been pointed out in the comments by @Alan. You must think of the ideal as the set of multiples of $f(x)$, as $(2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is not every integer, but rather only the even ones.

Now, to think about cosets is to think about "sending $(f(x))$ to the class of zero", in the sense that two polynomials are in the same coset if they differ by a multiple of $(f(x))$. Assume, for example, $f(x) = x^d+1$. Then, both $g(x) = x^d$ and $h(x) = -1$ are in the same coset, as $x^d = -1 + (x^d+1)$. One neat way to think about this in the particular case of polynomials, is to think about the quotient as an "arithmetic rule to reduce the degree".

Assume we have a polynomial, for example, $x^2-x+2$, and we think about $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(x^2-x+2)$. You must think about this as "sending this polynomial to zero". Then, you abuse notation and write $x^2-x+2=0$ (there is a formal way of doing this, but I'm trying to be ilustrative). You can "leave the $x^2$ term alone", and have $x^2 = x-2$, and use this rule to reduce the degree of polynomials. If you have $x^3-x$ and want to think about its coset, you realize $x^3-x = x(x^2-1)$, and you send $x^2$ to $x-2$, meaning the coset of $x^3-x$ is the same as that of $x(x-3)=x^2-3x$, and applying it again, it is the same as $-2x-2$. Quotients by polynomials of degree $d$ make you think about a space of polynomials of degree less than $d$, and give you a way of reducing the degree in case you go over.

Comment: I appreciate this alternative way of viewing things, but I'd like to clear out what's wrong with my coset intuition first. Yes, $(f(x))$ does not have all polynomials, but have at least a polynomial for any degree greater than 2

Comment: No you don't (in general). Note that in any integral domain (a very weak condition in almost every field of study, $\mathbb{Z}$ is one for example) multiplication of two polynomials adds their degrees. This means that every non-zero polynomial of $(f(x))$ will have at least the same degree as $f(x)$. The only elements of this ideal are its multiples. Also, every root of $f$ is a root of every polynomial of the ideal, and this doesn't happen for every other polynomial. The ideal is smaller than you think

Comment: So $R/I$ is the set of cosets $r + I$, but is $(f(x))$ the set of sets $f(x) + R$ or $f(x)R$?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why I can do these reductions? For $x^3-x$ and $-2x-2$ to be in the same coset, then we need to be able to find an element $a$ from $<x^2-x+2>$ such that $x^3-x = -2x-2 + a$, but I don't know how does $(f(x))$ looks like as I don't know if it's $f(x)$ multiplied or added with $R$

Comment: very good explanation +1

Comment: $(f(x))$ corresponds to $f(x)R$, at least in the case when the ideal is principal (generated by one element). To see the motivation, it might help you to think about the cosets of the quotient as being the sets such that if $a$ and $b$ are in the same coset, dividing by $f(x)$ gives the same remainder. That's why these cosets are sometimes called residue classes or remainder classes.

Comment: Two polynomials are in the same coset iff they have the same remainder when dividing by $f(x)$, iff they differ by a multiple of $f(x)$. Hence, taking any one of them, $a(x)$, and considering the set $a(x) + I$ where $I = Rf(x)$, we have every polynomial that differs from $a$ in a multiple of $f(x)$. That's the shape of the coset

Comment: Thank you, @Elaqqad , hope it helped